# Correct way to detect abstract objects / reference types?

Tags: javascript, jslint

When using

```
$P.isObjectAbstract = function (obj) {
    return obj === Object(obj);
};
```

I get the jslint error:

> line 77 character 31 Use the object literal notation {} or
>   Object.create(null).

However this form (below) produces different results.

```
$P.isObjectAbstractZ = function (obj) {
    return obj === Object.create(obj);
};
```

I use the term objectAbstract to differentiate from objectLiteral which would be of the mores simple form `var object_literal = {}`.

An objectAbstract is just something with keys that one can access as such `localStorage.some_key` ( more specifically this is a magical host object ).

Is there a jslint correct way to test for Abstract Objects?

Comment: Wouldn't you want `return obj === Object.create(obj);`? JSLint says `Object.create(null)` because it's referring to creating an empty object.

Comment: Oh haha okay, I thought I caught the problem :)

Comment: ... but a better question might have been, is there a difference between `Object(obj)` and `Object.create(obj)`

Comment: Well yeah. With `Object(obj)`, if `obj` isn't already an `Object`, it's "converted". If it's already an `Object`, I don't think it does anything. But if you look at what `Object.create` does - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create - it creates a new object and sets its prototype based on the first parameter. So I guess I would think that for custom `Objects`, the `return obj === Object.create(obj)` shouldn't work. I'm sorry but you can explain more what you're trying to accomplish? I'm just confused

Comment: Maybe you want `obj !== Object.create(obj)`. Again, I'm not sure of the purpose, so I don't know if that's right.

Comment: Even after fixing the typo, it does not work, as you stated, it will create a new object, so that I think it will never equal the original input.

Comment: So you want to see if an object is specifically an `Object`? Where `{a: 1}` would be true. But `[1, 2, 3]`, `"123"`, `123`, `true`, etc. would be false?

Comment: both of your I/O examples are correct, but passing jslint.

Comment: Yeah, good point, sorry for my confusion :)

Comment: Not sure why top coders like crockford and ashkenas can't agree on how to write good code.  If they can't how am I suppose to?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "I/O examples". But if you're referring to what I asked about being true or false, then you can use `return {}.toString.call(obj) === "[object Object]";`. Hopefully that's what you mean. Here's my example: http://jsfiddle.net/qMAYt/ . Is that what you mean?

Comment: ...that will detect object literals...it will not detect object abstracts....try ...  `Object.prototype.toString.call(localStorage) === "[object Object]"`

Comment: Interesting, did not expect that. Sorry I didn't add that to my original tests, when you specifically provided as an example. Hmmm I'll have to think through this more...

Comment: I just want to make sure - the other tests I provided worked properly? Like the results in the fiddle were what you want/expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSLint shows poor knowledge of Javascript here and thinks you are doing `new Object()`, which is not
the recommended way to create a new object. The recommended way is object literal or `Object.create`.

Calling `Object` with an argument is entirely different though.
It is often used to detect if something is a primitive type or a reference type.

You can work around JSLint by using:

```
$P.isObjectAbstract = function(obj) {
    return obj === {}.constructor(obj);
};
```

Note that like I said above, this does *nothing like* "detects abstract objects" like you describe. A proper name would be `isReference` or `isReferenceType` or whatever.

Comment: @pure_code.mom no, the `.constructor` of an `Object` is `Function`, whereas the `.constructor` of an `{}` is `Object`

Comment: Arrays still pass this "test"

Comment: @Ian arrays are references so it should return true for arrays

Comment: @Ian...that is O.K , I can modify my loop to test for arrays first, so they are filtered out, just thought of this.

Comment: @Esailija I guess I'm still thinking of satisfying the whole "abstract object" thing the OP wanted in the first place. But you even pointed out `this does nothing like "detects abstract objects" like you describe`

Comment: @Ian yeah I didn't read the comment thread. The OP wants something like jQuery's `isPlainObject` ?

Comment: ...this is fine...a reference type is what I call an abstract object.

Comment: @pure_code.mom in javascript arrays are reference types though, very different from PHP.

Comment: @Esailija Hmm very possibly, yes. It seems to satisfy `localStorage`, which I had a problem including. I didn't expect `Object.prototype.toString.call(localStorage)` to return "[object Storage]"

Comment: Note that even the version that fails jslint detects `[]` as it is a reference type.  I believe the answer Esailija posted is equivalent to the version I posted that fails jslint...

Comment: ... can you break down what this does ... `{}.constructor(obj);` Why does an object literal have a constructor property?  What is the input for? I've never seen this kind of code.

Comment: @pure_code.mom yes it is equivalent. `{}.constructor === Object`, given sane environment (in insane environment, `{}.constructor` has a better chance of working actually). `.constructor` is usually a property on objects that is a reference to the function that constructed the object.

Comment: @pure_code.mom You might want to look at the code for jQuery's `isPlainObject` method (as Esailija suggested) - it seems to be passing the tests you expect - object literals and `localStorage` both pass

Comment: @Ian it shouldn't pass `localStorage`, it is meant to detect plain objects.

Comment: @Ian then that's a bug in jQuery `isPlainObject`

Comment: @Esailija Good point haha. The docs mention it's inconsistent for host objects

Comment: let me clear it out. My function detects reference types, anything that is not a `string`, `boolean`, `number`, `undefined` or `null` is a reference type. jQuery `isPlainObject` attempts to detect plain objects, I.E. object literals and objects created `new Object()` etc. `localeStorage` is a magical host object, as far from plain object as it gets.